# background/font size change and remember

Tags: cookies

I want to create font size and background change buttons, which i know how to do it. The problem is with remember it, so if user will go to a different page, background and font will stay the same. How can i do it?

I was thinking about saving this in cookies. What do you think about that?

Is anyone can write an example of saving valible in cookies in wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can sett a cookie whit a variable:
Now it saves for one day.

```
$settings = $mybackground;
setcookie('background',$settings,time() + (86400)); // 86400 = 1 day
```

Print it in the body like an img whit this:

```
echo $_COOKIE['background'];
```

Comment: your comment says: 86400 = 1 day , and you multiply by 7, so you add 7days not one?

Comment: yeah a small typo. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin for the font: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/font-resizer/

Description of the plugin:

> This plugin allows you to give the visitors of your site the option to
>   change the font size. The plugin acts over jQuery and saves the
>   settings in a cookie. So the visitor see the same font size if they
>   revisit your site. Which content is going resized, the resize steps
>   and other options you can set on the admin page called "font-resizer".

It should be a start to get the background to changa also, just look how the font changes.

Comment: Thanks, but I need example of saving varible in cookies. If I would know that, I could save font, background etc. I know how to change iton website with jquery.